# UV unwrapping behaves in a weird way

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I made this sword (my first model without tutorials ever, so I might've made many dumb mistakes) and wanted to UV unwrap it. The problem is, when I unwrap, some parts of the mesh simply don't exist on the UV map (the crossguard, the other side of the blade, most likely some other things as well)[image]

When I unwrap just the blade, it functions fine, and I end up with the blade properly split along the seams
[image]

Here's the sword's file itself: https://www96.zippyshare.com/v/e5uxa0TH/file.html

I think my main mistake was that I didn't make the whole sword out of one mesh, instead I created the blade, crossguard and the handle pieces separately and then joined them together using booleans, but it still doesn't make it clear as to what is wrong with the model

Comment: Try unwrapping a single face of the part that otherwise doesn't unwrap. If it unwraps, then press Ctrl + Numpad Add, to increase the selection, and try again. This way eventually you will discover where's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So, first off, no I would say your biggest mistake thus far has been trying to make the whole thing be one solid mesh. That's completely unnecessary, doesn't even translate to how the object is made in the real world, and makes your job 5x harder for no reason. Keep them all as separate objects and only join them if you absolutely have to for a specific purpose. Most props are composed of several if not hundreds of separate individual objects.

I also would not have applied all of the modifiers, this just makes unwrapping a bigger pain than it needs to be. You can apply stuff like SubDiv after the fact if you want, but at least apply the seams and unwrap it while it's still low-poly and then apply it after than. The UVs usually subdivide just fine.

Just consider how much easier it is to unwrap this:

[image]

Than something like this:

[image]

Using the Boolean modifier also just introduces all kinds of silly geometry all over the place like random slivers of triangles floating between the blade and the cross guard.

[image]

[image]

Those make getting clean UVs much harder as well. AFAIK making them mesh watertight like this is only necessary for 3d printing, which I can't imagine that's what you're doing if you're also trying to UV unwrap it.

So when I first open your file, I selected the parts I could see were unwrapped and hid thoses and then selected all of what remained, and you can see that it does have "UVs" right there in the corner. They were basically all set to 0. Which you might have had them unwrapped before they got joined but it's likely that using the boolean modifier would have erased all of that

[image]

I added a few more seams because IMO the ones you had were not sufficient to get a good unwrap and this is what I got.

[image]

Also I would recommend you scale your object to something closer to real-world scale. It just makes navigating around the object easier. right now you have a sword that is like 50 feet tall.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I made it one solid mesh because I thought that's what it had to be in order to even make the UV unwrapping possible (I wanted to texture the model in substance painter later on). As for the UVs being at 0, is there any reason for that? I still don't really understand why that happens

Comment: It probably has something to do with the boolean mod, I'm not sure on the whole backend but I'm pretty sure it is creating all new geometry from scratch in Bmesh, and that doesn't give it UVs afaik. Usually you  would prefer to keep the indiv objects in blender separate, give them matching names for the HP and LP, like "blade_low, blade_high, handle_low, handle_high", and then Substance has a feature that matches them to eachother during baking.

Comment: You want to keep them separate, generally in Blender, and then export them as FBX by selecting all the "sub-objects" and then exporting them as one combined FBX

Comment: *>>>and you can see that it does have "UVs" right there in the corner.<<<* - that's where the unwrapped UVs reside, at the default initialization of floats, `0.0`.